# Elastic pendulum: First order ODE

Tags: simulations, differential-equations

I need to model an elastic pendulum. The spring has a spring constant $k$. Mass-, nominal pendulum length and gravitational constant are taken to be one. The model equations are give:

$$
\dot y_1 = y_3
$$

$$
\dot y_2 = y_4
$$

$$
\dot y_3 = -y_1\lambda(y_1,y_2)
$$

$$
\dot y_4 = -y_2\lambda(y_1,y_2) -1
$$

$$
\lambda (y_1, y_2) = k*\frac{\sqrt{y^2_1+y^2_2}-1}{\sqrt{y^2_1+y^2_2}}
$$

I don't understand where this equation comes from? What is $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$? Are this $x,y$ coordinates and its derivatives (veloctiy and acceleration)?

Comment: Ok - I am really sorry. Now the equations are correct. @MikeDunlavey: could you explain me in simple words what that mean? (is $y_1$ the x-cordinate in a plane and $y_2$ the y-cordinate; $y_3$ velocity in horicontal direction and $y_4$ velocity in vertical direction?

Comment: I have to say that the choice to write all the generalized coordinates and velocities as $y$ smacks of someone too beholden to a differential equations textbook for their own good. It needlessly obscures the problem and won't make the person making that decision popular in physics circles. Just write $x$, $y$, $v_x$ and $v_y$ so the reader will have some *hints* already!

Comment: @Kenni: The term $\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$ looks like $y_1$ and $y_2$ are just horizontal and vertical distances from the origin, and the root is the distance $D$. The term $k(D-1)/D$ is just $k$ if $D$ is large, and $-k/D$ if $D$ is small, and is $0$ when $D=1$. What this means is a mystery to me. Does this spring have a length of 1, and is it nonlinear?

Comment: @dmckee I agree 100%; but again: I got the equations without explaination and I am really thankful  for your help. So is the interpretation of the equation consistent: $y_1$ is the x-cordinate, $y_2$ the y-cordinate and $y_3, y_4$ the velocities?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Mass-, nominal pendulum length and gravitational constant are taken to be one

Comment: Hi Kenni. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the form of the equations we can surmise that

$y_1$ and $y_2$ are the horizontal and vertical position of the bob

$y_3$ and $y_4$ are the horizontal and vertical velocity of the bob

The rate of change of the velocity is given by the elastic force (hence the $\dot{y_3}=\lambda y_1$ etc. equations).

It is extremely unhelpful to create a set of equations like this in which $m=g=1$, so that you completely lose all sense of dimensions - and meaning.

If we wrote the equations as follows, you would probably be able to make sense of them:

$$v_x = \dot{x}\\
v_y = \dot{y}\\
L = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
\Delta L = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-L_0\\
m \dot{v_x} = F_x = \left(m g + k \Delta L \right) \sin\theta\\
m \dot{v_y} = F_y = \left(m g + k \Delta L \right) \cos\theta$$

Simplify these for small angles, and set m=g=L_0=1, and you get your equations.

Horrible.